# Angular Firebase: Querying documents with specific reference

Tags: angular, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

The problem I'm having is when trying to query documents with a reference of another document in a different collection. This is my actual context:

Two collections: "posts" and "users".
Each "posts" document has a "user_id" field (yeah, I come from SQL) which is a reference to a "users" document.
And each "users" document has an array of references to "posts" documents.

[image]

I don't know if this is efficient. I'm open to listen other ways to format my documents' relations.

I had this in mind:
**Arrays** of references? Creating **collections** in "users" documents? Or an actual **string**  field in each "posts" document with the UID of the "users" document?

I already tried using where() function to query but doesn't work with my actual schemas.

I'm using Express.js for the backend btw.

Comment: If posts has the uid, maybe you can try `db.doc(uid).get ()` to get the user document for a post

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured this on my own:

```
let listPosts = [];
  for (const post of user.list_posts) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
    listPosts.push((await db.collection('/posts').doc(post._path.segments[1]).get()).data());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must save the user ID (collection) in the document fields.

```
public user(data) {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('users').add(data).then(ref => {
      firebase.firestore().doc('users/' + ref.id).update({ id: ref.id });
    });
  }
```

after:If posts has the uid, you could try

```
 public getUsers(uid) {
    return firebase.firestore().doc('users/' + uid).get();
  }
```